# What does a jungle giant village look like?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, lore, golarion

I'm a ranger with a backstory around a jungle giant killing my mother which sets me off from learning druidic things (from my mother) to dedicating my life to tracking and killing this giant.  The setting is in the Skulls and Shackles adventure path.  But it made me wonder what a jungle giant village/settlement looks like.

[The Bestiary](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary3/giant.html#giant,-jungle) says that they organize into

> solitary, hunting party (2–9 plus 1–3 girallons), or tribe (10–40, plus 35% noncombatants, 1–3 druids or sorcerers of 2nd–5th level, 1 ranger or barbarian of 3rd–7th level, and 2–8 girallons).

It also describes them as

> Reclusive by nature, jungle giants lair deep within the rainforest. These giants distrust the ways of civilization and resent trespassers. More than one vine-covered lost city in the deep jungle owes its fall to jungle giant ire.

So the question is **What does it look like to stumble into a tribe of jungle giants?** Do they have huts? Caves? Sleep under trees? Tie trees together to form large huts? Cut down trees or rocks and stack them? Do they have fires? Are they nomadic? What do they eat?

As I'm typing this out, I wonder if some of this is up to the GM. Being set in Golarion, in a prebuilt adventure path, how much of this is already nailed down?

Comment: Answerers: We don't accept questions that are looking for ideas or speculation. This question previously asked what they “would” look like, which to avoid gathering speculative answers was changed to ask what they *do* look like. We expect authoritative answers backed by game material, not “Well *I* think…” answers. Previous speculative answers have been removed. Apologies to anyone who wrote an answer in good faith based on the original wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most correct response is, naturally, that your last comment is correct. The books provide a guideline, and idea of what the creatures are and do, but

**it is the GM that decides what each place looks like.**

It's up to them to sell the fantasy and sow the scene, so if they want them to be more or less progressed, it's whatever fits the campaign. The GM Guide and Cityscapes books have rules about [Settlements](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/settlements) that may lend a little more structure to the idea. If they want opinions/ideas, a forum may be a better medium to ask the question in.

[Heart of the Jungle](http://havocx42.aura.feralhosting.com/Pathfinder/Chronicles/PZO9222%20Heart%20of%20the%20Jungle.pdf) is a Pathfinder Chronicles that could also help set the scene. P17 has an example village that indicates

> Regardless of race, daily life within the many small villages 
>   that  dot  the  Mwangi  jungles  and  plains  proceeds  in  a 
>   remarkably  similar  fashion.